# How to get name of all methods in a scala trait

Tags: scala, reflection, traits

I need all the method names in a scala trait I've defined. I know this sounds like a trivial problem but I could not find any answers relating to the trait, they all revolved around classes.

To be specific, I need names for all the abstract methods. But if I can get the name of all methods regardless of abstract or not, that works too.

Say I have this trait A

```scala
trait A {
  def myDefinedInt: Int = 2
  def myAbstractString: String
}
```

I need a list of all methods (or preferably just the abstract ones)

I'm relatively new to scala so although I get classes and interfaces. Traits are new to me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get all methods with `getDeclaredMethods` and then just filter for abstract methods:

```
 import java.lang.reflect.Modifier

 classOf[A]
    .getDeclaredMethods
    .filter(m =>  Modifier.isAbstract(m.getModifiers))
    .map(_.getName)
    .foreach(println)
```

It prints: `myAbstractString`.

Comment: This could be simplified by combining `filter` and `map` into `collect`: `classOf[A].getDeclaredMethods.collect{ case m if  Modifier.isAbstract(m.getModifiers) => m.getName }.foreach(println)`

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik That's perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @AnilKumar Good to hear that :)